# how to add array without creating a id number?

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

```
$url = file_get_contents("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/000008?append_to_response=credits,images&api_key=###");

$json = json_decode($url, true)
$inp = file_get_contents('test3.json');
$tempArray = json_decode($inp,true);
$test = array($title=>$json);
array_push($tempArray, $test);                   
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
file_put_contents('test3.json', $jsonData);
```

when i add new array it creates a id number like this - >

```
"Ariel": {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "\/z2QUexmccqrvw1kDMw3R8TxAh5E.jpg",
        "belongs_to_collection": {
            "id": 8384,
            "name": "Proletariat Collection",
            "poster_path": null,
            "backdrop_path": "\/ibLeWo3X3dVo4rxvn4m3y90ms1I.jpg"
        },
"0": {
        "Varjoja paratiisissa": {
            "adult": false,
            "backdrop_path": "\/6YjUX87VtIEuDzanBE6obVxE9V3.jpg",
            "belongs_to_collection": {
                "id": 8384,
                "name": "Proletariat Collection",
                "poster_path": null,
                "backdrop_path": "\/ibLeWo3X3dVo4rxvn4m3y90ms1I.jpg"
            },
"1": {
        "Life in Loops (A Megacities RMX)": {
            "adult": false,
            "backdrop_path": "\/udvB86uyzJ6P9vmB83WfrCbnmnI.jpg",
            "belongs_to_collection": null,
            "budget": 42000,
            "genres": {
                "0": {
                    "id": 99,
                    "name": "Documentary"
                }
            }
```

first one is ok but then it adds new id number befire movie title .i Dont want to add id number. please can anyone help me how add new array without creating id number?

Comment: Where does `$title` come from

Comment: Give us an example of the json string you get from the api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. sort() can change the array indices into numbers.
2. JSON_FORCE_OBJECT may not need.

So:

```
 array_push($tempArray, $test);
 sort($tempArray);
 $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems incomplete but try to replace

```
$test = array($title=>$json);
array_push($tempArray, $test);
```

by

```
$tempArray[$title] = $json;
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the entries in the `test3.json` come from the same API (so have the same shape), just push the next entry in the array without setting a key manually.  In the long run you'll get an array of all movies that is easy to traverse.

```
$newMovie = json_decode($url,true);
$allMovies = json_decode(file_get_contents('test3.json'),true);
$allMovies[] = $newMovie;

$jsonData = json_encode($allMovies,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
file_put_contents('test3.json',$jsonData);
```